# How i can wait until the subscribe finish before return a value of another function

Tags: angular, typescript, service, rxjs

I have one simple project, that take the users data from JSON file and it will show the data of a single user in another page.
My 'teacher' tell me that i have to use 2 services to handle the users data, the service that handle the http request, and another service that take the observable and does the CRUD operations.

This is the HTTP service

> **user-Http.service.ts**

```
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  getBooks() {
    return this.http.get<User[]>(environment.userUrl);
  }
```

And this is the user service

> **user.service.ts**

```
 users: User[];
 user: User[] = new User;

  constructor(private userHttp: UsersHttpService) {
    userHttp.getBooks().subscribe(res => {
      this.users = res;
    })
   }

//...

  getUser(id: number) {
    this.userHttp.getBooks().subscribe(res => {
        if (res != null) {
          this.users = res;
          console.log(this.users.find(user => user.id == id))
          this.user = this.users.find(user => user.id == id);
          console.log('Return ', this.user)
          return this.user;
        }
      });
    }
//...
```

But when in the user-info component i call the getUser function the console return this error

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined
> at UserService.getUser (user.service.ts:23)

This is the user-info component

> **user-info.component.ts**

```
 public user: User
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private _userService: UserService) { }


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.subscribe(
      p => {
        this.user = this._userService.getUser(p.id);
      }
    )
  }
```

> **user-info.component.html**

```
{{user | json}}
```

After many console log i discover that the function getUser is executed before the subscribe ends, and for this reason it execute the find of an undefined array and throw this error.
How i can fix it?

Comment: why can't you combine userHttps.getBooks() and getUser() ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use subject to make sure you get the data only once they are retrieved from your service.

Your UserHttpService class is not changed but in your UserService class you add a subject to which the component will subscribe

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { UserHttpService } from './user-http.service';
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {
  private user: User;
  public userSelected = new Subject<boolean>();

  constructor(private userHttpServ: UserHttpService) {

  }

  getUserById(id: number) {
    this.userHttpServ.getBooks()
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe((res => {
        this.user = res.results.find(u => u.id == id);
        if (this.people !== undefined) {
          this.userSelected.next(true);
        } else {
          this.userSelected.next(false);
        }
      });
  }

  getUser() {
    return {...this.user };
  }
}
```

In your component you subscribe to the userSelected subject. You call getUserById, when the user is found the subject will emit true and your subscription will get the user data.

```
export class UserInfoComponent  {
  public user: User;
  private userSub: Subscription;

  constructor(private userServ: UserService) {
    this.userSub = this.userServ.userSelected.subscribe(res => {
      if (res) {
        this.user = this.userServ.getUser();
      }
    });
  }

  getUserById(id: number) {
    this.userServ.getUser(id);
  }
...
}
```

Don't forget to unsubscribe the userSub on ngOnDestroy to avoid memory leaks.

Here is an example :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ag2unt

Comment: Thank you very much! Thanks also for the newbies-proof explanation!

Answer (score 1):

I'd combine userHttps.getBooks() and getUser()

```
constructor(private userHttp: UsersHttpService) {}

  getUser(id: number): User {
    userHttp.getBooks().subscribe(res => {
      if (res != null) {
        this.users = res;
        return this.users.find(user => user.id == id);;
      }
      return null;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Nope, it return undefined

Comment: If i put a console log in the getUser function of `this.users.find(user => user.id == id);` it return the object, but when I do a console.log in the ngOnInit of the return of getUser, it returns undefined

Comment: can you please create a stackblitz link for this ?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zrvvhc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts  i'll tried

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) for nesting subscriptions.

In this way, you will not face the issue which you are facing now.

Also, try exploring map, exhaustMap, concatMap, MergeMap based on your requirement.

I have used map since the return is not observable, please find the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/array-filter-using-map)

Comment: I don't understand how it can help me, sorry

Comment: Ok.. let me make an example. I'll come back with one

Comment: Check the following stackblitz, https://stackblitz.com/edit/array-filter-using-map

Comment: Ahhh ok , now i understand. Using the find inside the map. I'll try

Comment: Nothing, it returns undefined in the user-info component, i tried it in stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zrvvhc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Angular calls `getUser()` before the HTTP call fetches the list of users. To fix it for now, either initialize the users array:

```
  users: User[] = [];
```

Or do the check in `getUser()`

```
 getUser(id: number) {
     return this.users ? this.users.find(user => user.id == id) : null;
 }
```